# Space before footnote reference mark?

Tags: footnotes

Is there supposed to be a space before a footnote reference mark?
For example:

> This is a sentence. <sup>1</sup>

(let's say 1 is the footnote number) or there isn't supposed to be a space, so,

> This is a sentence.<sup>1</sup>

Which is the preferred way?

Comment: There is no universal standard; such concerns are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, choose a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: What is a footnote reference mark?? Do you just mean a footnote number? Footnotes are generally numbered.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your referencing methods - APA, MLA, Oxford, Harvard, Chicago, etc.

Personally, I would omit the space.<sup>1</sup>

EDIT:

[Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/04/) is a good place to find information - and they, as well as Wikipedia, don't have spaces.

---

1 To get <sup>Superscript</sup>, use html formatting like the following <sup>1</sup>

Comment: But what do the reference methods suggest?

Comment: For a superscript 1, use Unicode 00B9 (185): ¹

Comment: I have never seen a style guide that suggests leaving a space before a footnote marker. (There may be some, but in 30 years of editing I haven't come across one...)

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking Could you please try to answer this [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/547901/1473)?